# How to remove specific character from a string?

Tags: java, string

I have a string that saves user login name and I want to remove specific characters from that string,i want to remove "@gmail.com" and just have the name before the @, then save it as a new string?

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried, otherwise it is a request for doing your work and that's off topic for this site.

Comment: what you have tried? First read and give a try. There are plenty of examples available on google.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, email can be any email address, not just gmail.com

```
public class Test  {

  public static void main(String[] args)  {

    String email = "nobody@gmail.com";
    String nameOnly = email.substring(0,email.indexOf('@'));
    System.out.println(nameOnly);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` + `replaceAll` method of string for eliminate it

**sample:**

```
    String s = "Rod_Algonquin@company.co.nz";
    String newS = s.replaceAll("@(.*).(.*)", "");
    System.out.println(newS);
```

will work on different sites extension.

if you want `.org`, `.net` , etc then you need to change the regex `@(.*).(.*)`

Comment: There's a problem with organizational emails, those that end in `.org` rather than in `.com`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza can always use an matcher or accept all extension

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin what about removing companyname.co.nz ? is it different?

Comment: @user3792722 it is not a email address. and yes different regex for that.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin its the company email address!, what different regex should I use? thanks

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin yes!! so I retrieved the user login name (which is the user email), and the i want to show only the user name without (@company.co.nz) in the dashboard. eg. Hello Rod_Algonquin!

Answer (score 0):

make sure the email format be correct then use "split" method to split the string from '@' character's position and use first portion of results.

```
var str = "username@amailserver.com"; 
var res = str.split("@");
var username = res[0];
```